# Is there a better way to create an actionListener to JButtons in a for-loop?

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, jbutton, actionlistener

I want to create a number of `JButton`s which symbolize a specific time-intervall. All `JButton`s share basically the same `actionListener`: They mark their specific intervall as "free" ("Frei") or "not free" ("Belegt"). To do that, they not only just have to change text, but they have to call a method of another class, which uses their intervall as `@parameter`.
I create the `JButton`s with naming `JLabel`s like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfIntervalls; i++) {
            String toolTextString;
            if(controller.getCalendar(calendarName).isFree(i, controller.getDayString(year, month, day))) {
                buttonText = "Frei";
                toolTextString = "Belegt";
            }else {
                buttonText = "Belegt";
                toolTextString = "Frei";
            }
            
            if(i%5 == 0) {
                gridx = 1;
                buttonGridy += 2;
                textGridy += 2;
            }else if(i < 5){
                gridx = (i%5);
            }else {
                gridx = (i%5) + 1;
            }
            intervallButtons[i-1] = new JButton(buttonText);
            intervallButtons[i-1].addActionListener((ActionListener) this);
            intervallLabels[i-1] = new JLabel(intervallLabelBuilder(i));
            intervallButtons[i-1].setToolTipText(String.format("als %s markieren", toolTextString));
            
            GridBagConstraints gbc_btnNewButton = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc_btnNewButton.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
            gbc_btnNewButton.gridx = gridx;
            gbc_btnNewButton.gridy = buttonGridy;       
            contentPane.add(intervallButtons[i-1], gbc_btnNewButton);
            
            GridBagConstraints gbc_labels = new GridBagConstraints();
            //gbc_lblNewLabel.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
            gbc_labels.gridx = gridx;
            gbc_labels.gridy = textGridy;
            contentPane.add(intervallLabels[i-1], gbc_labels); 
            
        }
    }
```

my `actionListener`-method is this because I know that `numberOfIntervalls = 12`, for quik ajustments, the `numberOfIntervalls` should be a variable, but it`s static and` final`:

```
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
         System.out.println("-----------");
            if(e.getSource() == intervallButtons[0]){
                if(!controller.getCalendar(calendarName).isLoaded(controller.getDayString(year, month, day)))
                        controller.getCalendar(calendarName).summonDay(controller.getDayString(year, month, day));
                if(controller.getCalendar(calendarName).isFree(1, controller.getDayString(year, month, day))) {
                    controller.getCalendar(calendarName).setFree(1, false, controller.getDayString(year, month, day));
                    buttonText = "Belegt";
                    intervallButtons[0].setToolTipText("Als Frei markieren");
                    
                }else {
                    controller.getCalendar(calendarName).setFree(1, true, controller.getDayString(year, month, day));
                    buttonText = "Frei";
                    intervallButtons[0].setToolTipText("Als Belegt markieren");
                }
                intervallButtons[0].setText(buttonText);
                intervallButtons[0].setEnabled(false);
                intervallButtons[0].setEnabled(true);

            }else if(e.getSource() == intervallButtons[1]){
                if(!controller.getCalendar(calendarName).isLoaded(controller.getDayString(year, month, day)))
                        controller.getCalendar(calendarName).summonDay(controller.getDayString(year, month, day));
                
                if(controller.getCalendar(calendarName).isFree(2, controller.getDayString(year, month, day))) {
                    controller.getCalendar(calendarName).setFree(2, false, controller.getDayString(year, month, day));
                    buttonText = "Belegt";
                    intervallButtons[1].setToolTipText("Als Frei markieren");
                }else {
                    controller.getCalendar(calendarName).setFree(2, true, controller.getDayString(year, month, day));
                    buttonText = "Frei";
                    intervallButtons[1].setToolTipText("Als Belegt markieren");
                }
                intervallButtons[1].setText(buttonText);
                intervallButtons[1].setEnabled(false);
                intervallButtons[1].setEnabled(true);
            }
            else if (e.getSource() == intervallButtons[2]){
                if(!controller.getCalendar(calendarName).isLoaded(controller.getDayString(year, month, day)))
                    controller.getCalendar(calendarName).summonDay(controller.getDayString(year, month, day));
                if(controller.getCalendar(calendarName).isFree(3, controller.getDayString(year, month, day))) {
                    controller.getCalendar(calendarName).setFree(3, false, controller.getDayString(year, month, day));
                    buttonText = "Belegt";
                    intervallButtons[2].setToolTipText("Als Frei markieren");
                }else {
                    controller.getCalendar(calendarName).setFree(3, true, controller.getDayString(year, month, day));
                    buttonText = "Frei";
                    intervallButtons[2].setToolTipText("Als Belegt markieren");
                }
                intervallButtons[2].setText(buttonText);
                intervallButtons[2].setEnabled(false);
                intervallButtons[2].setEnabled(true);
                
            }else if (e.getSource() == intervallButtons[3]){
                if(!controller.getCalendar(calendarName).isLoaded(controller.getDayString(year, month, day)))
                    controller.getCalendar(calendarName).summonDay(controller.getDayString(year, month, day));
                if(controller.getCalendar(calendarName).isFree(4, controller.getDayString(year, month, day))) {
                    controller.getCalendar(calendarName).setFree(4, false, controller.getDayString(year, month, day));
                    buttonText = "Belegt";
                    intervallButtons[3].setToolTipText("Als Frei markieren");
                }else {
                    controller.getCalendar(calendarName).setFree(4, true, controller.getDayString(year, month, day));
                    buttonText = "Frei";
                    intervallButtons[3].setToolTipText("Als Belegt markieren");
                }
                intervallButtons[3].setText(buttonText);
                intervallButtons[3].setEnabled(false);
                intervallButtons[3].setEnabled(true);
                
            }else if (e.getSource() == intervallButtons[4]){
                if(!controller.getCalendar(calendarName).isLoaded(controller.getDayString(year, month, day)))
                    controller.getCalendar(calendarName).summonDay(controller.getDayString(year, month, day));
                if(controller.getCalendar(calendarName).isFree(5, controller.getDayString(year, month, day))) {
                    controller.getCalendar(calendarName).setFree(5, false, controller.getDayString(year, month, day));
                    buttonText = "Belegt";
                    intervallButtons[4].setToolTipText("Als Frei markieren");
                }else {
                    controller.getCalendar(calendarName).setFree(5, true, controller.getDayString(year, month, day));
                    buttonText = "Frei";
                    intervallButtons[4].setToolTipText("Als Belegt markieren");
                }
                intervallButtons[4].setText(buttonText);
                intervallButtons[4].setEnabled(false);
                intervallButtons[4].setEnabled(true);
                
            }else if (e.getSource() == intervallButtons[5]){
                if(!controller.getCalendar(calendarName).isLoaded(controller.getDayString(year, month, day)))
                    controller.getCalendar(calendarName).summonDay(controller.getDayString(year, month, day));
                if(controller.getCalendar(calendarName).isFree(6, controller.getDayString(year, month, day))) {
                    controller.getCalendar(calendarName).setFree(6, false, controller.getDayString(year, month, day));
                    buttonText = "Belegt";
                    intervallButtons[5].setToolTipText("Als Frei markieren");
                }else {
                    controller.getCalendar(calendarName).setFree(6, true, controller.getDayString(year, month, day));
                    buttonText = "Frei";
                    intervallButtons[5].setToolTipText("Als Belegt markieren");
                }
                intervallButtons[5].setText(buttonText);
                intervallButtons[5].setEnabled(false);
                intervallButtons[5].setEnabled(true);
                
            }else if (e.getSource() == intervallButtons[6]){
                if(!controller.getCalendar(calendarName).isLoaded(controller.getDayString(year, month, day)))
                    controller.getCalendar(calendarName).summonDay(controller.getDayString(year, month, day));
                if(controller.getCalendar(calendarName).isFree(7, controller.getDayString(year, month, day))) {
                    controller.getCalendar(calendarName).setFree(7, false, controller.getDayString(year, month, day));
                    buttonText = "Belegt";
                    intervallButtons[6].setToolTipText("Als Frei markieren");
                }else {
                    controller.getCalendar(calendarName).setFree(7, true, controller.getDayString(year, month, day));
                    buttonText = "Frei";
                    intervallButtons[6].setToolTipText("Als Belegt markieren");
                }
                intervallButtons[6].setText(buttonText);
                intervallButtons[5].setEnabled(false);
                intervallButtons[5].setEnabled(true);
                
            }else if (e.getSource() == intervallButtons[7]){
                if(!controller.getCalendar(calendarName).isLoaded(controller.getDayString(year, month, day)))
                    controller.getCalendar(calendarName).summonDay(controller.getDayString(year, month, day));
                if(controller.getCalendar(calendarName).isFree(8, controller.getDayString(year, month, day))) {
                    controller.getCalendar(calendarName).setFree(8, false, controller.getDayString(year, month, day));
                    buttonText = "Belegt";
                    intervallButtons[7].setToolTipText("Als Frei markieren");
                }else {
                    controller.getCalendar(calendarName).setFree(8, true, controller.getDayString(year, month, day));
                    buttonText = "Frei";
                    intervallButtons[7].setToolTipText("Als Belegt markieren");
                }
                intervallButtons[7].setText(buttonText);
                intervallButtons[7].setEnabled(false);
                intervallButtons[7].setEnabled(true);
                
            }else if (e.getSource() == intervallButtons[8]){
                if(!controller.getCalendar(calendarName).isLoaded(controller.getDayString(year, month, day)))
                    controller.getCalendar(calendarName).summonDay(controller.getDayString(year, month, day));
                if(controller.getCalendar(calendarName).isFree(9, controller.getDayString(year, month, day))) {
                    controller.getCalendar(calendarName).setFree(9, false, controller.getDayString(year, month, day));
                    buttonText = "Belegt";
                    intervallButtons[8].setToolTipText("Als Frei markieren");
                }else {
                    controller.getCalendar(calendarName).setFree(9, true, controller.getDayString(year, month, day));
                    buttonText = "Frei";
                    intervallButtons[8].setToolTipText("Als Belegt markieren");
                }
                intervallButtons[8].setText(buttonText);
                intervallButtons[8].setEnabled(false);
                intervallButtons[8].setEnabled(true);
                
            }else if (e.getSource() == intervallButtons[9]){
                if(!controller.getCalendar(calendarName).isLoaded(controller.getDayString(year, month, day)))
                        controller.getCalendar(calendarName).summonDay(controller.getDayString(year, month, day));
                if(controller.getCalendar(calendarName).isFree(10, controller.getDayString(year, month, day))) {
                    controller.getCalendar(calendarName).setFree(10, false, controller.getDayString(year, month, day));
                    buttonText = "Belegt";
                    intervallButtons[9].setToolTipText("Als Frei markieren");
                }else {
                    controller.getCalendar(calendarName).setFree(10, true, controller.getDayString(year, month, day));
                    buttonText = "Frei";
                    intervallButtons[9].setToolTipText("Als Belegt markieren");
                }
                intervallButtons[9].setText(buttonText);
                intervallButtons[9].setEnabled(false);
                intervallButtons[9].setEnabled(true);
                
            }else  if (e.getSource() == intervallButtons[10]){
                if(!controller.getCalendar(calendarName).isLoaded(controller.getDayString(year, month, day)))
                    controller.getCalendar(calendarName).summonDay(controller.getDayString(year, month, day));
                if(controller.getCalendar(calendarName).isFree(11, controller.getDayString(year, month, day))) {
                    controller.getCalendar(calendarName).setFree(11, false, controller.getDayString(year, month, day));
                    buttonText = "Belegt";
                    intervallButtons[10].setToolTipText("Als Frei markieren");
                }else {
                    controller.getCalendar(calendarName).setFree(11, true, controller.getDayString(year, month, day));
                    buttonText = "Frei";
                    intervallButtons[10].setToolTipText("Als Belegt markieren");
                }
                intervallButtons[10].setText(buttonText);
                intervallButtons[10].setEnabled(false);
                intervallButtons[10].setEnabled(true);
                
            }else if (e.getSource() == intervallButtons[11]){
                if(!controller.getCalendar(calendarName).isLoaded(controller.getDayString(year, month, day)))
                    controller.getCalendar(calendarName).summonDay(controller.getDayString(year, month, day));
                if(controller.getCalendar(calendarName).isFree(12, controller.getDayString(year, month, day))) {
                    controller.getCalendar(calendarName).setFree(12, false, controller.getDayString(year, month, day));
                    buttonText = "Belegt";
                    intervallButtons[11].setToolTipText("Als Frei markieren");
                }else {
                    controller.getCalendar(calendarName).setFree(12, true, controller.getDayString(year, month, day));
                    buttonText = "Frei";
                    intervallButtons[11].setToolTipText("Als Belegt markieren");
                }
                intervallButtons[11].setText(buttonText);
                intervallButtons[11].setEnabled(false);
                intervallButtons[11].setEnabled(true);
                
            }
        }
```

it's incredibly long and barely ajustable with just one variable, so all I want is following code standing in the creating `for`-loop:

```
 if(!controller.getCalendar(calendarName).isLoaded(controller.getDayString(year, month, day)))
                        controller.getCalendar(calendarName).summonDay(controller.getDayString(year, month, day));
                if(controller.getCalendar(calendarName).isFree(1, controller.getDayString(year, month, day))) {
                    controller.getCalendar(calendarName).setFree(i, false, controller.getDayString(year, month, day));
                    buttonText = "Belegt";
                    intervallButtons[i-1].setToolTipText("Als Frei markieren");
                    
                }else {
                    controller.getCalendar(calendarName).setFree(i, true, controller.getDayString(year, month, day));
                    buttonText = "Frei";
                    intervallButtons[i-1].setToolTipText("Als Belegt markieren");
                }
                intervallButtons[i-1].setText(buttonText);
                intervallButtons[i-1].setEnabled(false);
                intervallButtons[i-1].setEnabled(true);
```

but it doesn't work, because the `actionListener` can only handle non-local Variables...
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: *"They mark their specific intervall as "free" ("Frei") or "not free" ("Belegt"). To do that, they not only just have to change text"* Use a `JCheckBox` of `JRadioButton` instead, then there's no need to change the text (or the geometry of the GUI). For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Make it with just 2 or 3 buttons. Once that's working, the technique should be easy to transfer to .. as many more as needed.

Comment: @AndrewThompson it's a good idea but I definitely need to call `controller.getCalendar(calendarName).setFree(int i, false, controller.getDayString(year, month, day));` and `int i` is different for every `JButton`, because it needs to be the `int i` from that `for`-loop. That's my problem.

Comment: *"That's my problem."* My problem is that I can't read code that's not (compiled & formatted) in my IDE, so don't try. Oh wait, that's not a problem. Not for me at least, as my interest in this is purely academic. Where is the MRE / SSCCE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and int i is different for every JButton, because it needs to be the int i from that for-loop.

One way is to set the "action command" for the button.

When you create the button you use:

```
JButton button = new JButton(...);
button.setActionCommand("" + i);
```

Then in the ActionListener you use:

```
int index = Integer.parseInt( event.getActionCommand() );
```